# Can I make jdbc 4.1 source level compatible with jdk 1.6?

Tags: jdbc, java

I have code that extends java.sql.Statement, java.sql.Connection and java.sql.DataSource.

My compatibility target is java 1.6, I don't want to make any use of specific features introduced by JDBC 4.1 in jdk 1.7.

But the jdk that is install by default on my system is Openjdk 7. I'd like to stick with that, but I nevertheless want to let my code target 1.6.

In Eclipse, I have set 1.6 as my target for compilation, but the jdk insists that I implement the new methods in java.sql classes... I created stubs, that do nothing but throw UnsupportedOperationException. So here are my questions:

- is there any solution to compile 1.6 source code with 1.7 sdk ?
- if not, is my choice of "implementing" the new methods as UnsupportedOperationException safe, as long as I don't use jdbc 4.1 specifities ?
- is there any connection pool that implements jdbc 4.1 ?

Comment: Any particular reason you do not just work with Java 6 instead in addition to what you have by default?

Comment: What exactly do you think a connection pool "implementing" JDBC does? It just manages connections, I don't see how it would relate in any way to the JDBC version used.

Comment: @thorbjorn: well, in fact I'm using the default package on Debian/Ubuntu. It happens that the packager made openjdk-7-jdk also provide java6-jdk. So it creates symlinks on installation faking a jdk6 environment. I would rather not manually remove them and install my own jdk. But I certainly will if this is the only solution.

Comment: Not sure, but I guess a connection pool implementing jdbc 4.1 would at least delegate calls to specific 4.1 methods to the underlying connection/statement/ ... And maybe it would be clever about try with resource...

Comment: If you want to compile with target 1.6 on Java 7, then you should also specify a bootclasspath which contains the Java 6 rt.jar. Java 7 should give you a warning when you specify target 1.6 (at least: Oracle JDK does).

Comment: @Mark ok, in fact I never bothered to understand what rt.jar was (I just did: it contains the standard classes of the jre). So at least I have learned something today. So I will try your suggestion. That said, what about my first approach: implement new jdbc methods as throw UnsupportedOperationException ? Will this bite me ?

Comment: You can simply implement it to throw SQLFeatureNotSupportedException. BTW: Have you ever considered to implement it using `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` instead?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In fact my implementations are just some kind of proxy already. They add some stuff (mainly hints or there postgresql equivalent, or rewrite some part of the request in a way the application is anaware). To do that I implement, override and then delegate to the real object. But I realize I could use Proxy (ala Spring Template)... thanks for the tip !

Comment: @MarkRotteveel regarding the use of SQLFeatureNotSupportedException, yes, this seems a better alternative to UnsupportedOperationException, as each new method throws SQLException in its signature, and SQLFeatureNotSupportedException is really meaning that, an unsupported (optional) feature.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC4.0 is for JDK1.6, and you should use conditional compilation to produce a JDBC4.0 compatible package.